# Derive complex number form its position in the plane

Tags: complex-numbers, plane-geometry

Suppose I have a circle of center $s$ and radius $r$ and four points $p1,p2,p3,p4$ (in order) on that circle. What is the formula for the middle point $m$ between $p1$ and $p2$ on the circle? In the input I only have these five complex numbers $s,p1,p2,p3,p4$ and a real number $r$.

[image]

Comment: Usually, the order in a circle is taken counterclockwise. In your drawing you have the points in *reverse* order.

Comment: How about $s + \sqrt{(p_1 - s)(p_2 - s)}$?

Comment: The hard part is that the formula doesn't tell you which of the two roots to take, they are in the opposite sides and I want the one that is in arc between $p1$ and $p2$ not the arc containing $p3$.

Comment: There isn't a purely algebraic form for it, my guess, since it isn't an algebraic property. What happens when $p_1+p_2=2s?$ That is, if they are opposite each other? There is no definition for that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ p_2' = \frac{p_2 -s}{p_1 - s}, p_3' = \frac{p_3 -s}{p_1 - s}$. Then $|p_2'| = |p_3'| = 1$. I'll assume that $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are all distinct. So $p_2' \ne 1, p_3' \ne 1$.

Let $\theta_2 = \arg p_2', \theta_3 = \arg p_3'$, where the angles are in $(-\pi, \pi]$.

If $\text{sign}(\theta_3) \ne \text{sign}(\theta_2)$ or $|\theta_3| \ge |\theta_2|$, then set $m' = e^{i\theta_2/2}$. Else set $m' = -e^{i\theta_2/2}$.

Finally $m = s + (p_1 - s)m'$.

$p_4$ is completely superfluous.

---

To avoid calculating args, we can define for $x^2 + y^2 = 1, y\ne 0$ that $$\sqrt{x+iy} = \sqrt{\frac{1+x}2} + i\left(\text{sign}(y)\sqrt{\frac{1-x}2}\right)$$

- If $p_2' = -1$, then $m' = -\text{sign}(\text{Im}(p_3'))i$.
- Else, if $\text{sign}(\text{Im}(p_3')) \ne \text{sign}(\text{Im}(p_2'))$ or $\text{Re}(p_3') < \text{Re}(p_2')$, then $m' = \sqrt{p_2'}$.
- Else $m' =-\sqrt{p_2'}$.

And again $m = s + (p_1 - s)m'$

Comment: It works well, thanks.

Comment: @Planetary - actually, looking over my second approach now, I see that it failed when $p_2$ is exactly opposite $p_1$, so $p_2' = -1$. So I've added a correction for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to give the circle midpoint of $p_1,p_2$ along the arc that doesn’t contain $p_3.$

We need the principal square root. If $s=0,p_1=1,p_2=z,p_3=-1,$ then the value is the principal square root of $z.$ It is built into the question.

If $p_3=-1$ and $s=0,$ then the midpoint can be found as $\sqrt{p_1}\sqrt{p_2},$ where we have the principal square root, defined and continuous everywhere other than the negative reals. (It can be defined at the negative reals, but not made continuous.) The value $\sqrt{p_1}\sqrt{p_2}$ is **one** of the square roots of $p_1p_2,$ but we don't know which sign it takes relative to the principal value of $\sqrt{p_1p_2},$ so we can't simplify.

Then in the general case of $p_1,p_2,p_3$ on a circle around $s,$ we can transform it via $f(z)=\frac{s-z}{p_3-s},$ which transforms the circle containing the $p_i$ to the unit circle, with $f(p_3)=-1,$ and preserving the arc angles. Essentially, $f$ rotates, translates, and scales the plane.

Then we can use:  $$f^{-1}\left(\sqrt{f(p_1)}\sqrt{f(p_2)}\right)=s+(p_3-s)\sqrt{\frac{s-p_1}{p_3-s}}\sqrt{\frac{s-p_2}{p_3-s}}$$

We can't use $\sqrt{u}\sqrt{v}=\sqrt{uv}$ or $u\sqrt{v}=\sqrt{u^2v},$ because these are not true for the principal square root.

This works for any $p_1,p_2\neq p_3.$

The principal square root is not purely algebraic. It is motivated by the algebraic notion of a square root, but the cut is motivated by the geometry of the question. It is fortunate that the principal square root is a very common choice, but it doesn’t have an algebraic meaning.

Comment: Based on some of the comments that Planetary made, in particular to user170231's answer, they are after the midpoint of the arc between $p_1$ and $p_2$ that does not contain $p_3$ and $p_4$ (which must lie on the same arc).

Comment: Thanks, fixed, @PaulSinclair

Answer (score -2):

I approach the problem as follows: let

$$
\zeta_1=\arg(p_1-s)\\
\zeta_2=\arg(p_2-s)
$$

with $\zeta_{1,2}\in[-\pi,\pi]$. Then

$$
m=s+re^{i\big(\zeta_2+\frac{\zeta_1-\zeta_2}{2}\big)}=s+re^{i\big(\frac{\zeta_1+\zeta_2}{2}\big)}
$$

Comment: Shouldn't be $(-\pi, \pi]$? Otherwise it's ambiguous what is $\arg$ when the number is a negative real.

Comment: @Planetary I got the same answer (yes to jjagmath's correction, and to be clear, $|m-s|=r).$

Comment: Your formula is symmetric according to $p1$ and $p2$ so how does it "know" where $p3$ is?

Comment: @jjagmath If the convention is, say, $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, then I believe my $[-\pi,\pi]$ to be correct.

Comment: @Planetary I don't believe that $p_{3,4}$ have anything to do with this, so long as they are laid out as shown. And, as an aside, it is customary to take successive points in the positive $\theta$ direction, thus counterclockwise. As was suggested by jjagmath in the comments.

Comment: @CyeWaldman The convention is not $[0,2 \pi]$, it's $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Thanks, butI  prepare the figure just to give an example what I mean, but from the responses it turns out it was misleading, I don't have the specific figure on input just arbitrary numbers that I know are placed points on some circle.

Comment: The direction can be later change from positive to negative by exchanging in the formula  $p1$ with $p2$ and $p3$ with $p4$ so ithe figure doesn't have to be redrawn.

Comment: @jjagmath The circle $z=e^{i\theta}$ requires $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ in order to be a circle.

Comment: @CyeWaldman No, it doesn't. $z = e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta\in [0, 2\pi)$ is the exact same circle.